# Mysql third table relationship SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I'm trying to run this query with three tables related as follows:

1. Table 1: ADS.

   - It has the field ADID (this is the unique id of the ad)
2. Table 2: USERS.

   - It has a field NAME (this is the user name).
   - Each user could be a salesman or not.
3. Table 3: SALESMAN.

   - It has the field USERID (this is the user id that captures the ad)

SALESMAN table has ADID to link ADID of ADS table. So each row in SALESMAN table keep the USER and the AD.

What I want is a list of the ADS table rows but with the NAME of the USER contained in USERS table (NAME) through the SALESMAN table.

**THIS IS MY QUERY**

```
SELECT  USERS.name AS Salesma
FROM    ADS AS N
        LEFT JOIN SALESMAN AS V1 ON N.adid = V1.adid
        LEFT JOIN USERS AS U1 ON V1.uid = U1.uid
```

I got the following error message:

```
Unknown column 'users.name' in 'field list'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' (around 15mins to an hour later)  by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 4):

use the `alias` provided instead of the table name,

```
U1.name
```

the full query

```
SELECT  U1.name AS Salesman
FROM    ADS AS N
        LEFT JOIN SALESMAN AS V1 ON N.adid = V1.adid
        LEFT JOIN USERS AS U1 ON V1.uid = U1.uid
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed604/6)